# Designing class in a constexpr manner

Tags: c++, constexpr

I'm not sure how to ask about my problem as it was a chain of decisions and not sure at what point I should have done differently, so let me explain fully my situation and then ask the questions.

I have a small GPIO driver on an embedded device, stripped down and simplified code looks like this:

https://godbolt.org/z/8GP7Y53rc

```
#include <cstdint>

namespace GPIO {

    enum class port_e:uint32_t {
        io0  = 0,
        io1  = 1,
        io2  = 2,
        io3  = 3,
        io4  = 4,
        io5  = 5,
        io6  = 6,
        io7  = 7,
    };

    enum class portMode_e:uint32_t {
        input  = 0b10,
        output = 0b01,
    };

    struct instance_s {
        uintptr_t baseAddress;
        uint32_t  numberOfIOs;
    };

    template<uint32_t baseAddress, uint32_t numberOfIOs>
    constexpr instance_s makeInstance() {
        // Check for valid base address
        static_assert((baseAddress % 4) == 0,                                          "The GPIO base port address needs to be 32-bit aligned");
        static_assert((baseAddress >= 0x7000'0000UL) && (baseAddress < 0x8000'2000UL), "The GPIO has to be within the APB bus range");

        // Check for valid number of IOs
        static_assert(numberOfIOs>0 && numberOfIOs<=8,                                 "The number of IOs in this GPIO port_s needs to be between 1-32");

        return {baseAddress, numberOfIOs};
    }

    template<const instance_s* thisGpio, port_e portId>
    void config(portMode_e mode) {
        static_assert(thisGpio->numberOfIOs > static_cast<uint32_t>(portId), "You are trying to access IOs above your numberOfIos configured in the instance");

        *(volatile uint32_t *)(thisGpio->baseAddress + static_cast<uint32_t>(portId)) = static_cast<uint32_t>(mode);
    }

}

constexpr auto gpioOut = GPIO::makeInstance<0x7000'5000UL, 2>();

int main(void) {
    GPIO::config<&gpioOut, GPIO::port_e::io0>(GPIO::portMode_e::output);
    GPIO::config<&gpioOut, GPIO::port_e::io1>(GPIO::portMode_e::output);

    return 0u;
}
```

Everything works as expected. I had to use template arguments because I wanted the code to be done at compile-time and allow static_asserts to validate the argument's values.

I make an *instance_s* structure that holds information about my current GPIO device (base address and how many pins it has) and then every command using the GPIO takes that *instance_s* structure at compile time and can execute code for that specific GPIO instance. My only problem is somebody could make the instance *instance_s* structure directly without calling *makeInstance* and would skip the validation assertions.

So I wanted to protect the *instance_s* structure type by changing the namespace into a class and making the *instance_s* structure private so *makeInstance* would be the only way to get the instance and all the calls would use the internal *instance_s* inside the class instead, so they wouldn't need to pass the *instance_s* structure externally. In-process *makeInstance* instead of returning the *instance_s* structure is returning the instance of the class. Now I have to hold the *instance_s* structure inside the class, so made a field but because I can't just initialize it at that moment, I can't have it as constexpr.

Can't use the template arguments with the class constructor and therefore I can't use the static_asserts in it, so the static *makeInstance* does the static_assert method which now instead of returning the *instance_s* structure it returns the instance of the class, while the constructor now has to be private as that one only takes arguments and populates the internal *instance_s* structure. In process of doing this I lost the constexpr of the whole thing. And now my stat_assert is failing: `error: non-constant condition for static assertion`

I know, because the field *thisGpio* holding my *instance_s* structure is not constexpr and I can't find a way to make it one, while achieving what I want.

https://godbolt.org/z/qrn8oEdza

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

class GPIO {

public:
    enum class port_e:uint32_t {
        io0  = 0,
        io1  = 1,
        io2  = 2,
        io3  = 3,
        io4  = 4,
        io5  = 5,
        io6  = 6,
        io7  = 7,
    };

    enum class portMode_e:uint32_t {
        input  = 0b10,
        output = 0b01,
    };

private:
    const uintptr_t baseAddress;
    const uint32_t  numberOfIOs;

    GPIO(uint32_t baseAddress, uint32_t numberOfIOs): 
        baseAddress(baseAddress), numberOfIOs(numberOfIOs) {}

public:
    template<uint32_t baseAddress, uint32_t numberOfIOs>
    constexpr static GPIO makeInstance() {
        // Check for valid base address
        static_assert((baseAddress % 4) == 0,                                          "The GPIO base port address needs to be 32-bit aligned");
        static_assert((baseAddress >= 0x7000'0000UL) && (baseAddress < 0x8000'2000UL), "The GPIO has to be within the APB bus range");

        // Check for valid number of IOs
        static_assert(numberOfIOs>0 && numberOfIOs<=8,                                 "The number of IOs in this GPIO port_s needs to be between 1-32");

        return GPIO(baseAddress, numberOfIOs);
    }

    template<port_e portId>
    void config(portMode_e mode) {
        static_assert(numberOfIOs > static_cast<uint32_t>(portId), "You are trying to access IOs above your numberOfIos configured in the instance");

        *(volatile uint32_t *)(baseAddress + static_cast<uint32_t>(portId)) = static_cast<uint32_t>(mode);
    }

};

auto gpioOut = GPIO::makeInstance<0x7000'5000UL, 2>();

int main(void) {
    gpioOut.config<GPIO::port_e::io0>(GPIO::portMode_e::output);
    gpioOut.config<GPIO::port_e::io1>(GPIO::portMode_e::output);

    return 0u;
}
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way to make the namespace more protected? Just when returning the structure instance as a handle to the GPIO instance, I'm in the process exposing the structure's type as well.

Or how to correctly structure the OOP approach and still have 0 runtime overhead similarly to the namespace approach?

Or is there a whole design pattern I'm missing which would solve this from a completely different angle?

Apologies for the multiple questions, just it looks like I do not have enough knowledge to even ask to correct question and I do not want to force somebody's hand by demanding that it needs to be done in an OOP style when the goal can be achieved easily with different programming style.

I'm using C++17 and it is my preference, but I could switch to C++20 if that would make it easier to answer.

Comment: so you want something along: `struct instance_s { private: instance_s(); friend GPIO; }`?. But it's super odd that GPIO has an instance. GPIO is a instance of itself, so GPIO should construct GPIO, not "instances" (of what?)

Comment: Although you can wrap everything into the `GPIO` class -- and it wouldn't necessarily be wrong to -- it sounds like what you actually wanted was to just hide the construction of `instance_s` from the users and make them have to call the factory function instead. You can either use `friend`ship for that, or -- if `friend`ship isn't allowed (e.g. due to org standards), you can make the function a `static` member function of `instance_s` so that it has access to the private constructors. That would make construction become `instance_s::make<...>()` though

Comment: @Human-Compiler Yes, I want to hide the structure and allow only the factory function. So I could make a small mini-class in the struct with its own factory.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks. Yes by making the GPIO in a OOP the GPIO would be instance itself, but would have to hold the values somewhere

Comment: So just hold the values... `GPIO {  uintptr_t baseAddress; uint32_t  numberOfIOs;`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, you right, I will edit the question and move them as they shouldn't be in the structure_s anymore in the OOP, however I think that will not affect the constexpr part of the problem

Comment: @KamilCuk updated the code in the question with your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @Human-Compiler and @KamilCuk here is one solution which moves the factory into the *instance_s* struct and makes the constructor private so only the factory function can be used.

https://godbolt.org/z/dcWGK1cxf

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

namespace GPIO {

    enum class port_e:uint32_t {
        io0  = 0,
        io1  = 1,
        io2  = 2,
        io3  = 3,
        io4  = 4,
        io5  = 5,
        io6  = 6,
        io7  = 7,
    };

    enum class portMode_e:uint32_t {
        input  = 0b10,
        output = 0b01,
    };

    struct instance_s {
        uintptr_t baseAddress;
        uint32_t  numberOfIOs;

        template<uint32_t baseAddress, uint32_t numberOfIOs>
        constexpr static instance_s make() {
            // Check for valid base address
            static_assert((baseAddress % 4) == 0,                                          "The GPIO base port address needs to be 32-bit aligned");
            static_assert((baseAddress >= 0x7000'0000UL) && (baseAddress < 0x8000'2000UL), "The GPIO has to be within the APB bus range");

            // Check for valid number of IOs
            static_assert(numberOfIOs>0 && numberOfIOs<=8,                                 "The number of IOs in this GPIO port_s needs to be between 1-32");

            return {baseAddress, numberOfIOs};
        }

        private:
        constexpr instance_s(uint32_t baseAddress, uint32_t numberOfIOs): 
            baseAddress(baseAddress), numberOfIOs(numberOfIOs) { }
    };

    template<const instance_s* thisGpio, port_e portId>
    void config(portMode_e mode) {
        static_assert(thisGpio->numberOfIOs > static_cast<uint32_t>(portId), "You are trying to access IOs above your numberOfIos configured in the instance");

        *(volatile uint32_t *)(thisGpio->baseAddress + static_cast<uint32_t>(portId)) = static_cast<uint32_t>(mode);
    }

}

constexpr auto gpioOut = GPIO::instance_s::make<0x7000'5000UL, 2>();

// constexpr auto rogueInstance = GPIO::instance_s{0x7000'5000UL, 2};   // will fail because the constructor is private

int main(void) {
    GPIO::config<&gpioOut, GPIO::port_e::io0>(GPIO::portMode_e::output);
    GPIO::config<&gpioOut, GPIO::port_e::io1>(GPIO::portMode_e::output);

    return 0u;
}
```

Wondering if I should just for the exercise sake try the 'friend' approach and try the OOP way to work as well.